# Does DolphinDB support -inf and inf when dividing by 0 like numpy?

Tags: python, database, numpy, time-series, dolphindb

I know in Numpy, if it is divided by 0, it could become -inf or inf. In DolphinDB, if dividing by 0, it will turn into NULL, it is hard for me to tell if the value is just NULL or caused by 0 division.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of DolphinDB doesn't support INF.